# how to convert string abcdefghijklmnop to a 4x4 matrix in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string to a matrix of 4x4 size. The matrix should contain the elements same as that of the string.
For eg.

```
String="1234567890111213141516";
```

I need to convert this to a 4x4 matrix in java.

```
a[0][0]=1;
a[0][1]=2;
```

and so on.
Can anyone suggest me the code for the same?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: The string of your example has 22 characters.  How are they to be split between the 16 entries?

Comment: Read any good java book. 2 Chapters (1. Loops and Constructs 2. Two dimensional arrays) it should not take more than 15 mins to solve your problem

Comment: @David : it is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g... its like that.

Comment: So it's not `"1234567890111213141516"` as stated in the question?

Comment: @david : it was 11, 12 , 13... it was like this.

Comment: Please work on the clarity of your question. The problem statement in the title disagrees with the body of the question which in turn disagrees with your comments. For this to be an answerable question, it needs to be clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Well, I guessed that it was supposed to be.  But how is the program supposed to know that it's 11, 12, 13, ... and not (say) 111, 21, 31, 4, 1, 51, 6 ?

Comment: @david : problem solved . What should i do in case i want to create a 44x4 matrix with its 4x4 being the same as discussed above and rest elements different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading a `String s = "1234567890abcdefghij"`, you can add below code snippet :

```
char[][] a = new char[4][4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        a[i][j] = s.charAt(4 * i + j);
    }
}
```

this will help you. This will work for only one digit character only.

Comment: well... this code is working according to my requirement. Also while loop could be used over here... running a while loop for while(int k<len){a[i][j]=s.charAt(k);k++;}

Comment: What should i do in case i want to create a 44x4 matrix with its 4x4 being the same as discussed above and rest elements different?

Comment: You can declare two more integer variables `row` and `column` and assign `44` and `4` to them. 

`int row = 44;`

`int column = 4;`

Change the code like below :

`char[][] a = new char[row][column];`

You can also change for loops like below :

`for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)`

`for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)`

Comment: how to print the values that have been stored to the 4x4 matrix from the string?

Comment: It's very simple. Just add `System.out.println(a[i][j]);` inside innermost `for` loop among two `for` loops like mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint:

```
a[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(str.charAt(4 * i + j));
```

Figuring out how to use this to populate the entire matrix is left as an exercise for the reader.

P.S. This will work for a 16-character `abcdefghijklmnop` string as in your title; if the string is longer, as in the question, there is no unambiguous way to parse it into a 4x4 matrix.

P.P.S. If all you need to do is set the elements to the consecutive numbers from 1 to 16, you don't need the string at all.

Comment: Hint: Requires a forloop nested in another forloop. +1 for making him get involved, but you can't be sure he totally understands every algorithm concept. `i` and `j` probably make no sense in that context

Comment: how do i copy a 4x4 arrays elements to the same position of a 44x4 matrix and then fill the other rows of the 44x4 matrix with other elements?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your question is an easy one, so I answer your question with some additional points that I think help you more than the answer itself:

First, this is the code:

```
int N = 4;
String delim = ",";
String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16";
String[] c = s.split(delim);
int[][] mat = new int[4][4];
int l = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++,l++)
        mat[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(c[l]);
```

Notes: 
Please
1 - don't a simple problem a real hard one!

if it's a hw you can convince the tutor about defining the string delimited with something like "," (if he/she insists) or whatever, and if this is a real project convince the customer, you don't want to torture yourself!

```
String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16";
```

2 - you said you want to split the string into a 4 x 4 matrix, what if you want a 5x5 matrix? So take advantage of constants, and the same for the delimiter

```
int N = 4;
String delim = ",";
```

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

You should run two for loops through your string and fill up the matrix.
(This can be done with one array too, but let's keep it simple.)

```
    String str ="1234567890111213141516";
    final int rowSize = 4;
    final int columnSize = 4;
    String[][] a = new String[rowSize][columnSize];
    // iterate
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columnSize; column++) {
            a[row][column] = String.valueOf(str.charAt(rowSize * row + column));
        }
    }
    // test
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columnSize; column++) {
            System.out.print(a[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. The output will look like this:
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 0 1 1 
1 2 1 3